# what's the algorithm about how to get all subsets from a char string without cover all distinct letters?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I've been struggling with a Subset algorithm question recently.

How to get all subsets from a char string?

Condition: each subset cannot cover all the distinct letters of the original char string.

For instance, abbc, [a,b,c] -> output->  a, b, c, ab, abb, bbc, bb, bc

**Subset: {abc}, and {abbc} should be removed!**

My initial thought is to preprocess the original string into a1b2c1, then go recursively, each recursive layer process one distinct letter. In the last layer, like here, we need process c, whether we should put c in the subset depends on the information passed down by previous layers.

I am not sure my idea is good, does anyone has ideas about this question?

Comment: what do you exactly mean by a subset? From the example, I see that you probably mean a substring, is that correct?

Comment: Create the powerset of the characters and remove those that don't meet the condition.

Comment: Yes, we could regard each solution as a substring. @pkacprzak

Comment: That's what I was thinking before. Each time when we create a possible-set, just check whether it meets the requirement. @assylias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the worst case scenario, you will have to process all 2^n subsets, therefore I don't think that you can do better time wise.
Your idea for an answer is pretty good that way.

The only piece of information that needs to be passed to the next recursive step is whether you've chosen all distinct characters until now or not. Which can be done with only one bit. Here's an example:

Denote value and count pairs as v[i] and c[i]. Let n denote the number of such pairs.
The state of the recursive function can be defined as

F(i, b) = Return all subsets including values > v[i]. b = 1, if these subsets should not contain all distinct members.
F(n, b) is a trivial solution to the above recursion.

You seek F(0, 1)

Naturally you'll have to iterate from j = 0 to c[i] to consider all possible cases, ie, how many v[i] the subset shall include.
For j = 0 or b = 0, next recursive set will have b=0
Otherwise it should be 1.

This should generate all subsets that you seek.

Comment: Based on your ideas, I think it is enough for us to only make the last recursive layer do some actions corresponding to the bit passed down. Eg. there's n recursive layer, layer i processes the v[i] with c[i]. For 1 to n-1 layer, if layer i choose v[i] to results, then it will AND 1 to the bit, else it will AND 0 to to bit.  @shebang

Comment: The last recursive layer n, only need to check the bit. If the bit == 1, means all previous layers add their distinct letters in the results, so last recursive layer should not add its distinct letter to the results. If the bit == 0, means some previous layer didn't add its letter to the result, then last layer can do the normal things as the logic from previous layers. @shebang

Comment: @JoJo The trivial solution F(n, b) is the last layer. What you are saying is correct. Only the last layer needs to check b. And yes, that AND logic is one way to achieve the calculation of b.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to cover only letters (i.e. the number of distinct objects is under 26, inclusive), then you can make a bit set that represents the "universe". This bit set would have `1` in a position of a letter that is in your alphabet, and zero for all other positions.

You can go recursively the way that you described, passing down the `universe` bit set, along with the `soFar` bit set, which represents the letters that have been added so far. When you reach an invocation where `soFar` is equal to the `universe`, you know that your bit set would have all available letters, and *not* add it to the list of results.

Comment: +1 - though you could say that you *prune* the recursion at the point that `soFar` equals `universe`.  In the OP's example (N-1 out of N letters), the difference is minimal, but it is significant for N-M out of N letters.